# memory management guidelines on foundation functions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

While memory management for the foundation classes are consistent and documented, i was surprised to find (via the friendly `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) that Foundation functions like e.g `NSStringFromSelector()` seem to return pointers to constant storage - which is at least not mentioned in the documentation for the function.

Is that behaviour documented somewhere? Are there any consistent guidelines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules are really just the same as those for Objective-C methods - as is illustrated by [these docs for the core foundation functions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).

So in your example, because the words `alloc`, `new`, `create` or `copy` are not present the object you get back is not owned by you (it will either have static storage or will be autoreleased).

Comment: I read it and somehow already managed to forget it again - thanks.

Comment: You obviously didn't "retain" it ;-)

Comment: Cocoa has its own memory management docs ( http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/ ). The rules are slightly different; CF has no autorelease, and Cocoa uses `new` where CF uses `Create`.

Comment: These memory management rules might help - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: @Peter - yeah, that's why I included both new and create in my list :-) But you are right to point out the difference since this became the accepted answer